# Error Building Lineage OS on macOS;unknown type name 'StringPiece'

Tags: macros, custom-rom

When I was trying to build my first custom rom based on 7.1.1 (lineage os) the following error occurred.

SPECS ARE :

Macbook pro 2015 retina
Ram:8GB
Storage:512
Processor Name: Intel Core i5
Processor Speed: 2.9 GHz
OS: MacOs Sierra 10.12.2
Xcode:8.2.1(8C1002)

Full Command text is given below:

```
vibhoothis-MacBook-Pro:los vibhoothiiaanand$ brunch oneplus2
including vendor/cm/vendorsetup.sh
build/core/product_config.mk:268: *** No matches for product "lineage_oneplus2".  Stop.
** Warning: 'oneplus2' is using CM-based makefiles. This will be deprecated in the next major release.
Looking for dependencies in device/oneplus/oneplus2
Looking for dependencies in device/oppo/common
Looking for dependencies in device/qcom/common
Dependencies file not found, bailing out.

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.1.1
LINEAGE_VERSION=14.1-20170129-UNOFFICIAL-oneplus2
TARGET_PRODUCT=cm_oneplus2
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53.a57
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-16.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
HOST_CROSS_OS=
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=NMF26V
OUT_DIR=/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out
============================================
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.1.1
LINEAGE_VERSION=14.1-20170129-UNOFFICIAL-oneplus2
TARGET_PRODUCT=cm_oneplus2
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53.a57
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-16.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
HOST_CROSS_OS=
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=NMF26V
OUT_DIR=/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out
============================================
Running kati to generate build-cm_oneplus2.ninja...
/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/build-cm_oneplus2.ninja is missing, regenerating...
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.1.1
LINEAGE_VERSION=14.1-20170129-UNOFFICIAL-oneplus2
TARGET_PRODUCT=cm_oneplus2
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53.a57
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-16.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
HOST_CROSS_OS=
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=NMF26V
OUT_DIR=/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out
============================================
art/build/Android.common.mk:51: unsupported HOST_ARCH=x86_64
build/core/binary.mk:1253: external/deqp/Android.mk: libdeqp: Unused source files: \
build/core/binary.mk:1253: external/deqp/Android.mk: libdeqp: Unused source files: \
build/core/binary.mk:1253: external/pdfium/third_party/pdfiumbigint.mk: libpdfiumbigint: Unused source files: bigint/BigInteger.cc bigint/BigIntegerUtils.cc bigint/BigUnsigned.cc bigint/BigUnsignedInABase.cc
build/core/binary.mk:1253: external/pdfium/third_party/pdfiumbigint.mk: libpdfiumbigint: Unused source files: bigint/BigInteger.cc bigint/BigIntegerUtils.cc bigint/BigUnsigned.cc bigint/BigUnsignedInABase.cc
./external/speex/Android.mk:56: TODOArm64: enable neon in libspeex
frameworks/av/camera/cameraserver/Android.mk:18: Target has integrated cameraserver into mediaserver. This is weakening security measures introduced in 7.0
build/core/package_internal.mk:143: Empty argument supplied to find-subdir-assets
find: /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/common/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libwifi-hal-mock_intermediates: No such file or directory
build/core/package_internal.mk:143: Empty argument supplied to find-subdir-assets
build/core/Makefile:53: Duplicate header copy: /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/obj/include/qcom/display/copybit.h
build/core/Makefile:53: Defined in: hardware/qcom/display-caf/msm8994/libcopybit/Android.mk hardware/qcom/display-caf/msm8994/libcopybit/Android.mk
build/core/Makefile:53: Duplicate header copy: /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/obj/include/qcom/display/copybit_priv.h
build/core/Makefile:53: Defined in: hardware/qcom/display-caf/msm8994/libcopybit/Android.mk hardware/qcom/display-caf/msm8994/libcopybit/Android.mk
build/core/Makefile:53: Duplicate header copy: /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/obj/include/qcom/display/c2d2.h
build/core/Makefile:53: Defined in: hardware/qcom/display-caf/msm8994/libcopybit/Android.mk hardware/qcom/display-caf/msm8994/libcopybit/Android.mk
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE oneplus2
build/core/dex_preopt.mk:74: warning: overriding commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/dex_bootjars/system/framework/telephony-ext_nodex.jar'
build/core/dex_preopt.mk:74: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/dex_bootjars/system/framework/telephony-ext_nodex.jar'
build/core/dex_preopt_libart_boot.mk:49: warning: overriding commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/system/framework/arm64/boot-telephony-ext.art'
build/core/dex_preopt_libart_boot.mk:49: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/system/framework/arm64/boot-telephony-ext.art'
build/core/dex_preopt_libart_boot.mk:49: warning: overriding commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/system/framework/arm64/boot-telephony-ext.oat'
build/core/dex_preopt_libart_boot.mk:49: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/system/framework/arm64/boot-telephony-ext.oat'
build/core/dex_preopt_libart_boot.mk:49: warning: overriding commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/system/framework/arm/boot-telephony-ext.art'
build/core/dex_preopt_libart_boot.mk:49: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/system/framework/arm/boot-telephony-ext.art'
build/core/dex_preopt_libart_boot.mk:49: warning: overriding commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/system/framework/arm/boot-telephony-ext.oat'
build/core/dex_preopt_libart_boot.mk:49: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/system/framework/arm/boot-telephony-ext.oat'
build/core/java.mk:334: warning: overriding commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/common/obj/APPS/Dialer_intermediates/src/src/org/codeaurora/presenceserv/IPresenceService.java'
build/core/java.mk:334: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/common/obj/APPS/Dialer_intermediates/src/src/org/codeaurora/presenceserv/IPresenceService.java'
build/core/java.mk:334: warning: overriding commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/common/obj/APPS/Dialer_intermediates/src/src/org/codeaurora/presenceserv/IPresenceServiceCB.java'
build/core/java.mk:334: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/common/obj/APPS/Dialer_intermediates/src/src/org/codeaurora/presenceserv/IPresenceServiceCB.java'
build/core/base_rules.mk:316: warning: overriding commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/root/res/images/charger/battery_fail.png'
build/core/base_rules.mk:316: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/target/product/oneplus2/root/res/images/charger/battery_fail.png'
Starting build with ninja
ninja: Entering directory `.'
[  0% 80/46297] host C++: libaapt2 <= ...se/tools/aapt2/filter/ConfigFilter.cpp
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++ -I device/oneplus/oneplus2/include -I /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/gen/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates -I external/protobuf/src -I /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/gen/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/proto -I frameworks/base/tools/aapt2 -I /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates -I /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/gen/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates -I libnativehelper/include/nativehelper \$(cat /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/import_includes) -isystem system/core/include -isystem system/media/audio/include -isystem hardware/libhardware/include -isystem hardware/libhardware_legacy/include -isystem libnativehelper/include -isystem frameworks/native/include -isystem frameworks/native/opengl/include -isystem frameworks/av/include -isystem frameworks/base/include -isystem tools/include -isystem /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/include -c    -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /applications/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.12 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.12 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fcolor-diagnostics   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /applications/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin  -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-parameter -UNDEBUG -fPIC -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_STREAMS -Wno-deprecated-declarations -D_USING_LIBCXX -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI -std=gnu++14 -std=c++11 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -nostdinc++  -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast  -Werror=address-of-temporary -Werror=null-dereference -Werror=return-type    -MD -MF /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/filter/ConfigFilter.d -o /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/filter/ConfigFilter.o frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/filter/ConfigFilter.cpp ) && (cp /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/filter/ConfigFilter.d /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/filter/ConfigFilter.P; sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\\\\$//' -e '/^\$/ d' -e 's/\$/ :/' < /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/filter/ConfigFilter.d >> /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/filter/ConfigFilter.P; rm -f /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/filter/ConfigFilter.d )"
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/filter/ConfigFilter.cpp:17:
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/ConfigDescription.h:20:
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/util/StringPiece.h:20:
In file included from external/libcxx/include/ostream:138:
In file included from external/libcxx/include/ios:216:
In file included from external/libcxx/include/__locale:21:
frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/locale.h:42:37: error: unknown type name 'StringPiece'
    bool initFromFilterString(const StringPiece& config);
                                    ^
1 error generated.
[  0% 80/46297] host C++: libaapt2 <= ...tools/aapt2/compile/XmlIdCollector.cpp
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++ -I device/oneplus/oneplus2/include -I /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/gen/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates -I external/protobuf/src -I /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/gen/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/proto -I frameworks/base/tools/aapt2 -I /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates -I /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/gen/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates -I libnativehelper/include/nativehelper \$(cat /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/import_includes) -isystem system/core/include -isystem system/media/audio/include -isystem hardware/libhardware/include -isystem hardware/libhardware_legacy/include -isystem libnativehelper/include -isystem frameworks/native/include -isystem frameworks/native/opengl/include -isystem frameworks/av/include -isystem frameworks/base/include -isystem tools/include -isystem /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/include -c    -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /applications/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.12 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.12 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fcolor-diagnostics   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /applications/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin  -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-parameter -UNDEBUG -fPIC -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_STREAMS -Wno-deprecated-declarations -D_USING_LIBCXX -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI -std=gnu++14 -std=c++11 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -nostdinc++  -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast  -Werror=address-of-temporary -Werror=null-dereference -Werror=return-type    -MD -MF /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/compile/XmlIdCollector.d -o /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/compile/XmlIdCollector.o frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/compile/XmlIdCollector.cpp ) && (cp /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/compile/XmlIdCollector.d /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/compile/XmlIdCollector.P; sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\\\\$//' -e '/^\$/ d' -e 's/\$/ :/' < /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/compile/XmlIdCollector.d >> /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/compile/XmlIdCollector.P; rm -f /Users/vibhoothiiaanand/Desktop/los/out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libaapt2_intermediates/compile/XmlIdCollector.d )"
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/compile/XmlIdCollector.cpp:17:
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/ResourceUtils.h:20:
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/NameMangler.h:20:
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/Resource.h:20:
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/ConfigDescription.h:20:
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/util/StringPiece.h:20:
In file included from external/libcxx/include/ostream:138:
In file included from external/libcxx/include/ios:216:
In file included from external/libcxx/include/__locale:21:
frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/locale.h:42:37: error: unknown type name 'StringPiece'
    bool initFromFilterString(const StringPiece& config);
                                    ^
1 error generated.
[  0% 80/46297] host Java: jarjar (/Us...IBRARIES/jarjar_intermediates/classes)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (49 seconds) ####
```

Answer (score 0):

Output is quite informative - there is an unknown type name 'StringPiece' at

```
frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/locale.h:42:37
```

Check whether include directive is present in file locale.h

```
#include "util/StringPiece.h"
```

and correct upon need.

If error persist, sync repos with force option

```
repo sync -j1 --force-sync
```